# Updating a cassandra wide row columns from different apps

Tags: cassandra

Are two apps updating different columns of Cassandra wide row an antipattern?

We have a use case where we want to write data to Cassandra from an app(app1). Another app(app2) that reads this data can flag it for a certain use case. App2 gets notified by app1  after changing a column of the wide row and app2 will update the row accordingly.

Assume app2 own loading data in Cassandra from a  slow REST service. The data does get expired over time. App1 reads this data and will notify app2 via queue to refresh at certain threshold of expiry.  App1 gets many calls from this data so essentially let's assume Cassandra acts as cache here. But between the request to refresh and the time taken by app2 to refresh there can be many request to app2 to refresh this data. I want to optimize this by asking app1 to update a column for this row before publishing a message to app2 stating a request for refresh is sent . Thus app2 will drop duplicate events for this row that is aldready being refreshed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question further? From my understanding of the question, it seems you can do it what you want.  Are you facing any difficulties in what are you doing?

Comment: We r not facing difficulties as we r in design phase. I update question with more details .

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem at all. Many Cassandra clusters host multiple apps and multiple clients connecting at the same time.

Multiple apps/clients updating data concurrently is not an issue at all. Cassandra is designed to handle requests at internet scale. Cheers!